# Why is GCM only usable for ciphers with a 128-bit block size?

Tags: gcm, blocksize

All block cipher modes of operation that I understand are generic schemes. They are not restricted by key size or block size. So why is GCM restricted to 128-bit block size?

Comment: For “what is it”, what reference materials (e.g. Wikipedia, the NIST specification) have you read, and what part don't you understand?

Comment: The way it's defined to be GCM restricts it to 128 bit. In detail it relies on a polynomial over a field of size 128 bit and you if you change this polynomial you can't call it "the GCM" anylonger. You can build something GCM-like for any block size.

Comment: @Gilles I've read bits and pieces about it. I know it's something like CCM.

Comment: @SEJPM Well *why* can't it be generalized?

Comment: @Melab It can be generalized, but there are many equally valid generalizations and the designers didn't bother to pick particular ones.

Comment: @SEJPM You can easily use a 128 bit polynomial together with a 64 bit block cipher. You just need to use 2 blocks per message to mask the MAC and 2 blocks per-key to compute the MAC key. In principle you could even use a stream cipher instead of a block cipher, since GCM first uses CTR mode to build a stream cipher and then adds GHash on top of that stream cipher.

Comment: @CodesInChaos, [I'm not too sure](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/24838/23623) if you actually can say that you can use GCM with any stream cipher.

Answer (score 2):

The field polynomial used for GHASH limits most definitions to 128-bit block size. That does not mean you could not define it for other sizes – the proposal defined it for 64-bit as well ([pdf](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/BCM/documents/proposedmodes/gcm/gcm-spec.pdf), see Appendix A) even if NIST did not standardize that.

However, defining it for *arbitrary* block sizes would be more difficult. You would need to define a deterministic method for constructing the polynomial and the changes that entails (see the document above). Since 64-bit block ciphers are usually considered too small these days anyway and no larger block sizes are in common use, there is no need to do that.

Comment: To make things worse, GHash's security doesn't scale down well to 64 bit MACs or smaller fields.